# Regex validation (RegularExpressionValidator and Javascript) not working

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I'm facing a problem with Asp:RegularExpressionValidator. It shows [invalid quantifier] error in browser when validation (client side) happens. I think, this is related with some escape characters somehow, but couldn't make it work after trying few attempts. So, seeking for help!!!!

The regex is about validating an email address and found from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Y0. Just to mention, if this link doesn't open, the regex is like this

```
^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$
```

Can anybody please suggest how to fix the issue and make the validation works properly?

Note : I have already tried by pasting the regex directly with Javascript code to see it that works there or not. The code written to test is like, 
var match = new RegExp(emailRegex).exec(emailAddressValue);

Another note : Pasting the regex into C# code and performing validation on server side with Regex works well! So, something is really not working with javascript and regex.

Comment: Don't forget... the RFC allows a lot more than you'd think for a "valid" email address. http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx

Comment: Chase +1 I was surprised by some of those!

Comment: no joke. I've come to the conclusion that I should just let the user enter whatever they like for data, and if they don't get my email, it's on them... easiest email validation `Trim(email);`

Comment: however, realistically many MTAs and email clients are way more restrictive than the RFC. Do you really want people to use root@localhost as their email address?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# guy, but that doesn't look like standard regex escaping for quotes... try this:

```
^(?:(\")(\"[^\"]+?\"@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?:(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$
```

See it in action [here](http://rubular.com/r/W1mpysVMlM), (very strange capture groups...)

Comment: Niall, The double quotes are actually escaped itself (C# compiler would need it, otherwise it would see terminated string there). The site you provided uses "Server Side" validation (AJAX POST), but I need it to be validated client side.

Comment: Javascript doesn't support look behinds, that appears to be the other problem that prevented it working when you pasted it in.  With the quoting standardized and the look behind removed, the regex doesn't error out in javascript... this makes it look like it needs to be redesigned to avoid the look behind.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is the pattern syntax, javascript doesn't support look behind.
Personally the pattern looks a little overly explicit to me. As has been mentioned earlier the email address RFC is very permissive.

I notice your pattern also requires the domain ends in a maximum 6 characters. If you really want to cover all the edge cases you'll have to considder things like the [.museum](http://www.nic.museum/) TLD

Personally I find a more permissive pattern like this works much more effectively.

`\S+@(\w+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}`